# Dtexec ISSERVER returns is not a valid server package path

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, dts, dtexec

I am executing a SSIS package via master..xp_cmdshell from a stored procedure and I am always getting the error

> "Description:
>   '\SSISDB\Main\Projects\ProjectName\Packages\PackageName.dtsx' is not a
>   valid server package path."

I tried various kinds of permutations and combinations on the path, but it is not helping. This package was migrated from SQL 2008(MSDB) to SQL 2016(SSISDB) and I am leveraging the dtexec command (that was earlier using MSDB and now updated to point to SSISDB). What am I doing wrong?

```
dtexec /ISSERVER "\SSISDB\Main\Projects\ProjectName\Packages\PackageName.dtsx"  
/SERVER SERVERNAME /CONFIGFILE "D:\WorkSpace\Configurations.dtsConfig"  
/CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E /SET  
"\Package.Variables[User::LogId].Properties[Value]";718801
```

This is how it looks like in [SSMS-2016 tree view of the package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MS1Ol.png)
[image]

Thanks,
Arvind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out that you need to remove "Projects" and "Packages" from the folder path. (Found about this after running the package manually and verifying the Folder Location mentioned in the Package Name from execution report).

So it should be called as given below:

```
dtexec /ISSERVER "\SSISDB\Main\ProjectName\PackageName.dtsx" /SERVER SERVERNAME
 /CONFIGFILE "D:\WorkSpace\Configurations.dtsConfig" /CHECKPOINTING OFF 
/REPORTING E /SET "\Package.Variables[User::LogId].Properties[Value]";718801
```